# Increment NSUserDefaults number each day at midnight (excluding weekends)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, increment

I am making an app that automatically shows a list of classes in a schedule rotation. I have the core functionality complete, but my objective is to have the user enter the rotation number on first launch, and then increment Monday-Friday in the background, and **not** on the weekends. For example, if the user downloads the app on a Friday and enters that day as a Day 5, it should stay day 5 until Monday, and then would become Day 6. I would also like it to update it if the user doesn't open the app for a few days. Here is my current code:

```
- (void)checkIfDayChanged {
NSDate *open = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"openDate"];
NSDate *close = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"closeDate"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSString *openString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:open];
NSString *closeString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:close];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
BOOL weekend = [gregorian isDateInWeekend:open];

NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [close timeIntervalSinceDate:open];
NSInteger days = ((NSInteger)distanceBetweenDates) / (60 * 60 * 24);

if (![openString isEqualToString:closeString]) {
    if (!weekend) {
        [userDefaults setInteger:[userDefaults integerForKey:@"dayNumber"] + days forKey:@"dayNumber"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
    }
}
```

The problem is that to my understanding, iOS can only check this when the app is opened, not in the background, is this correct? And also, this does not account for not incrementing the values on weekends.

Comment: Are you letting us guess what's wrong with this code? I'd suggest you tell us.

Comment: @meaning-matters I'm sorry, I wrote this in a hurry earlier today. I edited to explain the main 2 problems.

Comment: It's clear now. Why do you want to update when the app is not opened? I mean, calculating the next rotation number can be done when the user opens the app again, how would he notice?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a server and also need to download content periodically, have a look at [background fetch](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1). You could then put your rotation number update code in there is you really have to. Be aware that you should not use a background fetch if you have no content to load over internet.

Getting the weekday should help you a lot:

```
NSDate*   date    = ...;
NSInteger weekday = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday 
                                                   fromDate:date];
```